# Debugging exceptions with jQuery 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-3

I recently upgraded from jQuery 2.4.1 to 3.2.1, and now I'm noticing that any exception that occurs during document ready handling (inside `$(function() { ... })`) instead of giving proper traceback and allowing me to inspect local variables/call stack now breaks in jQuery code and has no usable debugging information whatsoever:

[image]

Is this known behavior, and is there any workaround, besides switching back to old jQuery for debugging?

Comment: yes its by design: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3447

Comment: One workaround would be to use `Promise.all()` and chaining `.then()` and `.catch()` to each function call which returns a `Promise` to handle any errors, or not including chained `.catch()` to each `Promise` where an error should reach `.catch()` chained to `Promise.all()`